# Can not find any @Not annotations in spring boot v3.01

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate-validator

I'm trying to implement  validation in spring boot but can not find `@NotBlank`,`@NotNull`,`@NotEmpty` , any of the annotations. I specially want to use `@NotBlank` for my entity fields.

**I've tried with the following depenednecies:**

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Final'
```

---

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:8.0.0.Final'
```

---

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-cdi:8.0.0.Final'
```

---

```
implementation 'org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator-annotation-processor:8.0.0.Final'
```

---

```
implementation 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1'
```

---

**Both**

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator-cdi:8.0.0.Final'
    implementation 'org.glassfish:jakarta.el:'
```

---

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-annotations:3.5.6-Final'
```

---

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

**Hibernate website**
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-gettingstarted **says use both**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.0.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.expressly</groupId>
    <artifactId>expressly</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

**But I'm not able to find the `glassfish.expressly`**

**build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.0.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.0'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '19'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.mysql:mysql-connector-j'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

**SOMEBODY HELP WITH ME TO IMPLEMENT THE VALIDATIONS If SpringBoot has removed the `@NotBlank`,`@NotNull`,`@NotEmpty` validations in V3.0.1**

Comment: I guess they are now in `jakarta.validation.*` package instead of `javax.validation.*`. So you need to replace the old imports with the new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Spring Boot 3.0, just need to add a `validation` starter. It will add the bean validation APIs and implementations(Hibernate Validator) for you.

In your Gradle build script, add the following

```
dependencies{
    // ...
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
}
```

**Refresh your Gradle build**, and all the annotations will be available in the package `jakarta.validation`.

Comment: I've mentioned this dep in my question already. I tried it as well earlier. And I did it now again. But not working. And when I try to import manually like this `import jakarta.validation`  it gives ne error `import jakarta.validation can not be resolved. And `@NotBlank` shows `Not Blank can not be resolved to a type`

Comment: @MNouman After adding the deps in Gradle script file directly, you have to refresh Gradle build cache manually. Or remove your project specific files(.idea, *.iml) etc, and reimport the project. Else your deps in IDE will not be updated.

Comment: And now how to do that....and why to do that>

Comment: I tried this `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` , after some processing the terminal  showed `Build Successful` and terminal shut down. Than I tried to import the `@NotBlank` and it didn't come. I am facing still the same erros even after running `/gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` twice

Comment: [Get started with Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/getting_started.html) firstly, then read [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/guide/tutorials/working-with-gradle) to learn Gradle in IDEA, finally get to know spring via [the official guides](https://spring.io/guides#gs), to learn spring in depth, buy a book (pro spring,  spring in action)please.

Answer (score 0):

With Help of **@Hantsy** and after soo many tries I found the solution. I tried by reloading IDE window. I tried with `./gradlew build --refresh-dependencies` but it also **didn't not work** for me.

**Solution**

**Indeed the following dependency is used for the solution of my question**

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'
```

**BUT the reason it wasn't working because the `Gradle` was not refreshing the dependencies**

**So to make it work I the `rebuild project` in my `VC CODE`**

**Whenever you add new dependencies always `rebuild` your project**